# Size of typedef does not change after malloc

Tags: c, struct, malloc, realloc

I have a small code that starts an rtsp server. After I start a specific server I add the information regarding to the server such as its processor id (because I start each server as a sub-process), what kind of source it has, port and mounting point name to an array of struct which I call `rtsp_server_list`. I have a `static int server_count = 1` at the beginning of code which increases by 1 whenever I add a new server. So my `add_server()` function is as follows:

```
struct rtsp_server_list* add_server() {

    char  *port, *mountName, *source;
    pid_t child_process_id;
    printf("Server count: %d\n", server_count);
    struct rtsp_server_list *server = malloc(server_count*sizeof(struct rtsp_server_list));
    printf("Size of server list: %lu\n", sizeof(server));

    source = malloc(256);
    port = malloc(256);
    mountName = malloc(256);
    g_print("Enter a source: ");
    scanf("%255s", source);
    g_print("Enter a port: ");
    scanf("%255s", port);
    g_print("Enter a mount name: ");
    scanf("%255s", mountName);
    child_process_id = fork();
    if (child_process_id < 0) {
        perror("Fork for child failed.\n");
    } else if (child_process_id == 0) {
        g_print("Child process... \n");         
        execl("/home/tunc/workspace/gstreamer_rtsp_server/Debug/gstreamer_rtsp_server", "/home/tunc/workspace/gstreamer_rtsp_server/Debug/gstreamer_rtsp_server", source, port, mountName, NULL);
    } else {
        g_print("Child created, child is running.\n");
    }
    server[server_count-1].source = strdup(source);
    server[server_count-1].mountName = strdup(mountName);
    server[server_count-1].port = strdup(port);
    server[server_count-1].process_id = child_process_id;
    server_count++;
    // wait a bit to not mess the console outputs.
    sleep(1);
    return server;
}
```

In the above code, size of `*server` never changes, it always stays at 8 bytes. But when I add a server `server count` increases by 1 so if I happen to add a 2nd server, `*server` should have size 16. Is it because I don't allocate memory for the `char` arrays in the struct? My struct is as follows:

```
struct rtsp_server_list {
    char *source;
    char *mountName;
    char *port;
    pid_t process_id;
} rtsp_server_list;
```

I also have a code that removes an rtsp server by terminating its process but I am also not able to update the list in the way that I want. So what I am doing wrong? I tried doing these with `realloc` but results are exactly same.

Comment: `sizeof` gives you the size of the *type* of the object, not the size of an  allocated memory area (you cannot retrieve the latter via standard means). `sizeof` is a pure compile-time construct. `sizeof(server)` (or `sizeof server` as some would tell you) always returns the size of the *pointer to the struct* (which is usually 8 bytes on a 64bit machine).

Comment: @dhke `sizeof` may be resolved at runtime, e.g. `scanf("%d", &x); char ch[x];  printf("%zu", sizeof ch);`  . (Although OP is not using such constructs).

Comment: @M.M This is actually supported now? Well then, make it *is usually resolved at compile time and only ...*. Thanks for the heads up.

Comment: Oh now I get why it didn't print the size of the array. But I still have issues removing a server from the list. When I decrease the size of the list it simply doesn't update.

Comment: @TunçArslan That might be for another question. Because the current code allocates a new list whenever `add_server` is called (and creates a memory leak while at it). Did you want to use `realloc()` instead of `malloc()`? Oh, linked lists are great for this stuff, too.

Comment: @dhke I tried both `malloc()` and `realloc()` but the results are same. Originally I used `realloc()`. Also where is the memory leak? Is it because I don't free the memory? I thought functions were local so they free the memory after the function returns.

Comment: @dhke I guess it does not free the allocated memory and a good practice would be to write an inline function instead?

Answer (score 3):

`sizeof(server)` will give the size of the pointer, not the total size of the array.

It is implementation dependent (8 bytes in your case)